# How to deal with limited Human Effigies

Tags: dark-souls-2

This is more of a general question, but I have a real problem with the way this game handles the difficulty.  Back in the first Dark Souls, humanity wasn't growing like weeds, but there were ways to either farm it or get more then enough to survive on while you're playing.  You're also not given as much of a penalty for being hollow, other then not being able to summon.

However, in Dark Souls 2, it's gotten harder AND they've increased the penalties of being hollow.  Before, I read that the more hollow you are, the less likely people are to invade you, as well as it being less likely that you'll find a summon sign.  However, I'm finding that you NEVER can find a summon sign.  And, what's more, I've found myself invaded harder the more hollow I am.

Am I missing something here?  I know it's supposed to be harder, but with no way of getting your human body back easily, this makes the game more frustrating and tedious then it is fun.  How do I deal with the fact that I have a very limited supply of human effigies?  Before, simply helping someone kill a boss got you your human form back.  Now, it only gets you souls, so you can't get your human form to help beat your own boss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big help is getting the ring of Binding: http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/ring-of-binding. This cuts down the effect of being hallowed, and dying multiple times.

I personally find the game slightly easier than Dark Souls, because of a lot better placed bonfires and the possibility to skip / bypass certain bosses. At least until your better geared.

Comment: I do have the ring and have used it.  But I don't agree on it being easier, because the difficulty isn't coming from lack of HP.  It's coming from invasion, no help on bosses, and being locked out of upgrades until late game.  Not the point of this question, but weapon upgrades being half way through the game is unfair.

Comment: Upcoming patch 1.03 will implement "helping someone will restore your humanity".

Comment: The Ring of Life protection will stop you from turning Hollow at all, and you keep your souls when you die. It breaks after this, but the blacksmith only charges 3000 souls to fix it. So you end up doing that over and over again while the Human Effegies pile up in your inventory.